# Service Error on findNext of a TextFinder instance with over ten thousand rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am running a search for a keyword on a large data set in one sheet in Google Sheets.  I only need to search in one column of this large data set.
It is failing at the line that performs the search [findNext()] on a previously created TextFinder instance.

I ran a line by line debugging by adding Logger.log entries and stopping the execution of the function with return false;.
It stops the execution at the findNext() function with error "Service error".  I've faced this error before, it happens when too many calls to the spreadsheet class are made without updating it, the solution is to include some SpreadsheetApp.flush() sentences here and there to clear some buffer.  I added this line to no avail before and after findNext().  Of course it runs okay when I flush before findNext, but then it stops again at findNext, it never gets to the flush if I put it after findNext.

```
function searchByZipCode()   {
  var sheetSample1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeAllZIPs = sheetSample1.getRange("C:C");  // 13,165 rows in this range
  var textFinderResults = rangeAllZIPs.createTextFinder("10550");
  var strCounties = [];
  while (true)  {
    var rangeThisZip = textFinderResults.findNext();   // Service error!
    if (rangeThisZip)  {
      strCounties.push(sheetSample1.getRange(rangeThisZip.getRowIndex(), 1).getValue());
    }  else  {
      break;
    }
  }
  strCounties.forEach(function (Item, Index)  {
    Logger.log("Counties \[" + Index + "\]\: " + Item);
  });
}
```

#### Expected behavior:

Find the text I'm searching for in column C and provide me the values of column A in that spreadsheet.

#### Actual results:

Error message at around 10 to 15 seconds of execution on findNext() function.

Unfortunately I cannot provide a sample of a spreadsheet due to security restrictions in my network, but if you have a spreadsheet with 13,165 Rows with just two or three columns, let's say a list of counties in column A, two-letter state list in column B and their corresponding zip codes in column C you will see this behavior.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete function along with public access to an example spreadsheet so that we can verify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to search a value from the column "C" and retrieve the values of the column "A" at the row which found the value.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Issue:

Also in my environment, when `findNext()` and `findAll()` are used for `TextFinder` retrieved from `getRange("C:C")` and `getRange("C1:C")`, I could confirm that the same issue occurred. But when `findNext()` and `findAll()` are used for `TextFinder` retrieved from `getRange(1, 3, sheetSample1.getLastRow(), 1)` and `getDataRange()`, no error occurs. From this situation, I thought that it might be a bug. Or it might required to use the fixed range.

In order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var rangeAllZIPs = sheetSample1.getRange("C:C");
```

To:

```
var rangeAllZIPs = sheetSample1.getRange(1, 3, sheetSample1.getLastRow(), 1);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the method of `findAll()` is used.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

```
function searchByZipCode() {
  var sheetSample1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeAllZIPs = sheetSample1.getDataRange();
  var textFinderResults = rangeAllZIPs.createTextFinder("10550");
  var strCounties = textFinderResults.findAll().map(function(e) {return e.offset(0, -2).getValue()});
  strCounties.forEach(function (Item, Index)  {
    Logger.log("Counties \[" + Index + "\]\: " + Item);
  });
}
```

### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [findNext()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findNext())
- [findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findAll())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, I tried Pattern 1 with the same results as before, the same error message after a few seconds of execution, this is the end modification: `var rangeAllZIPs = sheetSample1.getRange(2, 3, sheetSample1.getLastRow(), 1);`
I'll try Pattern 2 and I'll come back with the results.

Comment: I also tried Pattern 2 @Tanaike and that worked like a charm, you've answered my question, thank you!!

Comment: @Elizabeth Ortiz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.